# how can i add fonts to show persian or arabic text in eclipse using itext?

Tags: android, eclipse, pdf-generation, itext

I want to show persian text using itext in Pdf. when i want to createfont an error occur that say myfont.ttf can not be embedded due to licensing restrictions.

this is my code.

`BaseFont bf =BaseFont.createFont(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Y.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);`

how can i solve this error?

thanks for your answer.

Comment: Use another font: if the license of your font says that you can not embed the font in a document, then it would be illegal to do so. Any answer to this question could be considered as helping somebody to do something that is illegal, except if the answer is: use a font that allows embedding.

Comment: i do not want to do illegal thing. i just want to solve my problem.

Comment: i do not have any problem with anyone or anything and i do not want to injure someone. i just want to somebody help me solve my problem.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie: what type of font i must use. can you please send me a link of a font that can help me.

Comment: i solved this my self. i used font tahoma.ttf and i can see persian characters.